# How to make the Overview button transparent

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I noticed many apps makes the overview buttons transparent automatically.
There is a way in react-native to accomplish this (in device that make it possible)?
I'm talking about those (samsung in this case):
[image]

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive#sticky-immersive

Comment: thanks, but the question is about react-native in expo env

Comment: this is the feature request discussion https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/hide-android-bottom-buttons--fullscreen-mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ORIGINAL SOURCE: https://medium.com/@elliothesp/detecting-android-soft-navigation-keys-in-react-native-30163abd7113

In order to make the System Navigation translucent, you have to add this to `android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml`:

```html
<!-- Customize your theme here. -->
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">
  @android:color/transparent
</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">
  true
</item>
```

Comment: thanks, so the answer is no, it cannot be done in Expo currently. It can be done in plain React native.